# Invalid type is displayed when using ethereumjs-tx

Tags: web3js

This is my code. It now reports an error of Invalid type. I guess there is a problem with Tx, but I don’t know how to solve it.

```
//ETH转账
    const send = async() =>{
      //1、构建转账的参数
      //获取账户交易的次数
      //await 必须是异步函数 加asncy
      const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address.value);
      //获取一下预计转账的gas价格
      const gasprice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice()
      //转账金额以wei为单位
      const value = Web3.utils.toWei('0.01','ether')

      //构造交易对象
      const rawTx = {
        from:address.value,
        nonce:nonce,
        gasprice:gasprice,
        to:'0x0015B5D608CC1422Fef0ffbAA93a8A8dAC2D1b2b',
        value:value,
        data:'0x0000',
      };
      console.log(rawTx)

      //2、生成serializedTx
      //转化私钥  去掉0x
      //const priKey  = Buffer(privateKey.value.slice(2), 'hex');
      var priKey = Buffer.from(privateKey.value,'hex');
      //const priKey = Buffer(privateKey.value, 'hex');
      console.log("priKey",priKey)

      //gas估算
      const gas = await web3.eth.getGasPrice(rawTx)
      //rawTx新增一类gas属性
      rawTx.gas = gas;
      //console.log("1")

      //ethereumjs-tx实现私钥加密
      const tx = new Tx(rawTx);
      tx.sign(priKey);
      
      //生成sarializedTx
      const sarializedTx = tx.serialize();
      console.log(sarializedTx)
      //sarializedTx = '0x' + sarializedTx.toString('hex');
      

      //3、开始转账
      const trans = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction("0x" + sarializedTx.toString("hex"));
      console.log(trans)
      //监听交易结果    txid:本次交易的hash值
      trans.on('transactionHash',(txid)=>{
          console.log("交易ID",txid)
          console.log('https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/${txid}')
      })
    };
```

it displays ERROR

> invalid type
> at toBuffer (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/bytes.js:196:11)
> at Transaction.setter [as nonce] (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/object.js:47:38)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/object.js:100:38)
> at Array.forEach ()
> at Object.defineProperties (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/object.js:98:20)
> at new Transaction (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/ethereumjs-tx/es5/index.js:113:13)
> at send (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=unplugin-vue-components!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/web3api.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js:77:18)

i try to use

```
var priKey = Buffer.from(privateKey.value, 'hex');
```

but it is not work,maybe it is no important.who can tell me why and how to correct it.